# CSS font import not returning a font change

Tags: html, css, fonts

Hey I've recently started working on some CSS projects, I was wondering why my font import wasn't working, the following code is what I have written for the font and nothing is being returned as a change of font.

@font-face {
font-family:gamefont;
src:url(raw.githubusercontent.com/DaddyVryl/kalam/main/kalam-v11-latin-700.woff2);
}

Comment: fonts file not found it links to download the file

Answer (score 0):

If you need to import some fonts it is better to do it with HTML with these lines inside your header:

`<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">`

`<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>`

`<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Kalam:wght@300;400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">`

and then use this in CSS:

`font-family: 'Kalam', cursive;`

Or you can import directly into your CSS with this:

`@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Kalam:wght@300;400;700&display=swap');`

And if you have the font downloaded on your PC then this should work:

`@font-face{font-family: fontName; src: url('../fontURL');}`

change "fontNAme" for the name of your font, and "fontURL" for the url where you have that font

I recommend for the "Good practices" that you always use fonts from the web, for example Google Fonts, and import them from your HTML.